# absolute path with database and collection name - not "use dbname" before command

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

How to specify in MongoDB 3.2.8 an absolute path?

I do this

```
use mydb
db.mycollection.findOne()
```

Howto write that without `use mydb`? The absolute path to db and collection. I use `mongo` shell.

Edit after first answer:

I have many databases and when specify a database a login time, to switch database I would again have to use `use otherdb`. I really wish some kind of absolute path, this is also possible in MariaDB/MySQL (`select * from mydb.mytable`).

Answer (score 1):

when you connect to mongod when open console, you can specify db to conncet to:

```
$ mongo mydb
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: mydb
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-08-27T00:21:59.200+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-27T00:21:59.200+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-08-27T00:21:59.200+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-27T00:21:59.200+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-27T00:21:59.200+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-08-27T00:21:59.200+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-27T00:21:59.200+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> db
mydb
```